# Filtering CSV File using AWK

Tags: linux, csv, awk, filtering

I'm working on CSV file

[This my csv file](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BySm1eeiEVzlOVBhSHBDSmF3bWM&usp=sharing)

Command used for filtering  `awk -F"," '{print $14}' out_file.csv > test1.csv`

This is an example of my data looks like i have around  43 Row and 12,000 column
i planed to separate the single Row using awk command but i cant able to separate the row 3 alone (disease).

i use the following command to get my output

```
awk -F"," '{print $3}' out_file.csv > test1.csv
```

This is my file:

```
gender|gene_name  |disease         |1000g_oct2014|Polyphen |SNAP 
male  |RB1,GTF2A1L|cancer,diabetes |0.1          |0.46     |0.1  
male  |NONE,LOC441|diabetes        |0.003        |0.52     |0.6  
male  |TBC1D1     |diabetes        |0.940        |1        |0.9  
male  |BCOR       |cancer          |0            |0.31     |0.2  
male  |TP53       |diabetes        |0            |0.54     |0.4
```

note "|" i did not use this a delimiter. it for show the row in an order my details looks exactly like this in the spreed sheet:

[image]

But i'm getting the output following way

```
Disease
GTF2A1L
LOC441
TBC1D1
BCOR
TP53
```

While opening in Spread Sheet i can get the results in the proper manner but when i uses awk the , in-between the row 2 is also been taken. i dont know why
can any one help me with this.

Comment: in the image there indeed are pipes to separate fields.

Comment: `awk -F'|' '{print $3}' file` wouldn't change the order. Can you explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: Show us the output of `head out_file.csv` so we can see what's really being given to awk.

Comment: you said you didn't use `|` as FS, spaces (default) neither. You used `,(comma)` in your codes, I cannot see how can you get your output from your input. E.g. the first line has no `comma` at all, why `Disease`  was printed out there?

Comment: Hi kent i dont have reputation to add this file to my post  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BySm1eeiEVzlOVBhSHBDSmF3bWM&usp=sharing this is the link containing my data. i can also share my csv file if you want

Comment: Hi jas. my original CSV file can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BySm1eeiEVzlOVBhSHBDSmF3bWM&usp=sharing the following link the command i used is awk -F"," '{print $14}' out_file.csv > test1.csv and my output file is also available in the same link. the first row in the column are correct but my data is not in the proper manner in the output file

Comment: No, just [edit] showing a [mcve]. We cannot go and download external files, etc. Also, you may want to read [ask].

Comment: I can see you have comma-separated values, where some of the values themselves have commas. Those values are delimited by quotes as appropriate for CSV format. Unfortunately awk isn't so great for dealing with files like that. If you're exporting from excel, try using a different separator (tab or "|", e.g.) that you know won't occur in your values. That will make things much easier.

Comment: Please can you also add some sample data to your question in a text format.

Comment: @jas but this is the output file given from the program. i cant able to change it. that's the problem is there any other way to filter this

Comment: @Sobrique cant get you. text format means you want to see my CSV file ??

Comment: That file you've uploaded - doesn't look like the data you quote in your question.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking. We gave you many hints on how to make things clear but no improvement whatsoever has arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last this is what i did for getting my answers in a simple way thanks to @peak i found the solution

1st i used the 
CSV filter which is an python module used for filtering the csv file.
i changed my delimiters using csvfilter using the following command

```
csvfilter input_file.csv --out-delimiter="|" > out_file.csv
```

This command used to change the delimiter ',' into '|'
now i used the awk command to sort and filter

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR == 1 {print} {if ($14 < 0.01) print }' out_file.csv > filtered_file.csv
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is - you have comma separated values with embedded commas.

That makes life more difficult. I would suggest the approach is to use a csv parser.

I quite like `perl` and `Text::CSV`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

open ( my $data, '<', 'data_file.csv' ) or die $!; 

my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { binary => 1, sep_char => ',', eol => "\n" } );

while ( my $row = $csv -> getline ( $data ) ) {
   print $row -> [2],"\n"; 
}
```

Of course, I can't tell for sure if that actually works, because the data you've linked on your google drive doesn't actually match the question you've asked. (note - perl starts arrays at zero, so `[3]` is actually the 4th field)

But it should do the trick - `Text::CSV` handles quoted comma fields nicely.

Comment: i will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the link you provided ("This is my file") points to two files, neither of which (at the time of this writing) seems to correspond with the sample you gave.  However, if your file really is a CSV file with commas used both for separating fields and embedded within fields, then the advice given elsewhere to use a CSV-aware tool is very sound.  (I would recommend considering a command-line program that can convert CSV to TSV so the entire *nix tool chain remains at your disposal.)

Your sample output and attendant comments suggest you may already have a way to convert it to a pipe-delimited or tab-delimited file. If so, then `awk` can be used quite effectively.  (If you have a choice, then I'd suggest tabs, since then programs such as `cut` are especially easy to use.)

The general idea, then, is to use `awk` with "|" (or tab) as the primary separator (`awk -F"|"` or `awk -F\\t`), and to use awk's `split` function to parse the contents of each top-level field.